# Unicode characters in iText PDF

Tags: java, swing, special-characters, itext

I need help with iText I look at some Google result and some here but don't find anything that work for me. I need to use polish character in my pdf but i got nothing for no. Here is a code that I think is important if need something else write in comment:

```
private static Font bigFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD);
```

another

```
Paragraph par = new Paragraph(Łabadzak, bigFont);
```

Can any1 tell me what to do to make that Ł visible in pdf and other polish character

**UPDATE**
I fund this but dunno how to use it for my project
[Polish character in itext PDF](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Polish-National-Characters-are-not-getting-displayed-in-the-PDF-created-by-iTExt-td2163833.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need a unicode font. Here is an example:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Şinasi ıssız ile ağaç", new Font(bf, 22));

document.add(p);
```

http://abdullahakay.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-itext-unicode.html

**EDIT:**

Here, the font file name `arialuni.tff` is a static resource directly under `/src/main/resources/` and can be any Unicode Font File of your choice. [Here](https://www.fontspace.com/category/unicode)'s a list of free Unicode Font Files available online.

Comment: OK i do this with u code and something I take from Kamil thx for help

Comment: Way with using FontFactory:

FontFactorygetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12)

Comment: How to register new font as a static field of class for example MyFont? To use it anywhere I want to as MyFont.ARIALUNI

Answer (score 7):

It depends on used font and encoding. i found something like this:

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Polish-National-Characters-are-not-getting-displayed-in-the-PDF-created-by-iTExt-td2163833.html

There is example like this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", 
BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); 
Font font = new Font(bf, 12); 
String polish = "\u0104\u0105\u0106\u0107\u0118\u0119"; 
document.add(new Paragraph(polish, font));
```

Remember that some fonts does not contain polish national characters.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using com.itextpdf.kernel package you can use any encoding which is not present in PdfEncodings class

```
PdfWriter writer ;
writer = new PdfWriter( dest ) ;
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument( writer ) ;

Document document = new Document( pdf ) ;

FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont( ) ;
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont( fontProgram, "Cp1254" ) ;
document.setFont( font );
```

for turkish characters I used "Cp1254"