# I can't add the ₺ (Turkish Lira) icon to the file with Java PDFWriter

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-writer

```
BaseFont bfSpecial = BaseFont.createFont("get_font/verdana.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Font my_font = new Font(bfSpecial, 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
    
document.add(new Paragraph("\n",my_font));
document.add(new Paragraph("*(₺₺₺₺₺)*",my_font));
document.add(new Paragraph("\n",my_font));
```

My Output
[image]

How to View the ₺ (Turkish Lira) sign on PDF?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128162/unicode-in-pdf help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in iText PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9556678/5221149)

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions, but I've reviewed them all, and unfortunately they're not appropriate. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Your code looks like you use itext as pdf library, not some core JRE class, for pdf creation.

Comment: it's very true. Do you want to suggest a different path? @mkl

Comment: I would suggest mentioning that library in the question and adding the tag [tag:itext].

Comment: ahh, I'm so sorry, yes, you're so right. Thanks. @mkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I just had to use the font "DejaVuSerif.ttf" for the solution. [you can download the font here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-serif)

```
BaseFont bfSpecial = BaseFont.createFont("get_font/DejaVuSerif.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bfSpecial, 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

Comment: In other words, your *verdana.ttf* simply does not contain a glyph for the ₺ (Turkish Lira) icon, and the solution is to use a font that does.

Comment: I can display the ₺ (Turkish Lira) icon with verdana.ttf in JTable. But I couldn't view it in a PDF. @mkl

Comment: JTable apparently uses a replacement from another font. Itext on the other hand simply does what you tell it to.